# Odd exception when trying to run an SQL query from VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I have this code:

```
Dim connstring As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(" Select * from Table_1 Where date_register >= @date_register And date_register <= @date_register2", conn)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@date_register", SqlDbType.Date).Value = "#" & DatePicker.value & "#"
cmd.Parameters.Add("@date_register2", SqlDbType.Date).Value = "#" & DatePicker2.value & "#"
'Dim myreader As SqlDataReader
If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
  conn.Open()
End If
Dim myreader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
conn.Close()
```

It produces this error:

[image]

What is the cause of the error and how can I solve it?

Comment: The error screenshot (strongly suggest you include the *text* of the exception type, message and stack trace in this Q) bares no resemblance to the quoted code.

Comment: I guess a UserControl called DatePicker has a function called `value` and when it's called in `DatePicker.value` you notice that nobody implemented the function yet. Just as guess as you should add more information such as the line from which the Exception originates in your code

Comment: Also the title of your question makes no sense

Comment: Remove the method. It's **not doing anything**, and is likely causing a naming conflict with one of the DatePicker controls, so the `value` property is interpreted as a method call.

Comment: You are showing a method that explicitly throws a `NotImplementedException` and you're asking us why a `NotImplementedException` is thrown? It's thrown because you're throwing it. If you don't want it thrown the don't throw it. If you expect that method to do something then write code to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The VB language has three quirks not found as often in some other languages:

1. It's not formally case sensitive (though the VS IDE is case-aware)
2. You can call methods with or without parentheses.
3. The `=` operator pulls double duty for both assignment and equality comparison

With that in mind, we can consider this line of code (and the similar line following):

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@date_register", SqlDbType.Date).Value = "#" & DatePicker.value & "#"
```

First of all, the `#` characters appended to each side of the date value are neither needed nor helpful. In fact, they will cause the value that was *already a date* to be converted to a string, and then also likely prevent the string from being correctly re-parsed as a date on the other end at all. Instead, you want to assign `DatePicker.value` directly to the parameter value.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@date_register", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DatePicker.value
```

But going beyond that, we have two places on this line using a `.Value` identifier matching the function name with the error:

```
.Add( ).Value
```

and

```
DatePicker.value
```

Given the quirks mentioned earlier, **both** of these can potentially cause confusion or naming conflicts with the function definition from the error message.

While the first one is intended as the left hand side of an assignment, item 3 above allows the `=` operator to be seen as an equality comparison, which in combination with item 2 makes it possible to interpret `.Value` expression as a method call instead of a property. But I don't think this is the issue, because it would be very odd indeed for the parameter expression to match the type name of a class and have a naming collision with the method from the error.

But now we have `DatePicker.value` (or `DatePicker2.value`). If either of those controls happens to match the name of the method's class, now you have a real naming conflict, where both a local DatePicker control and a DatePicker class could be valid ways to resolve this expression, and the compiler can choose to call the unimplemented method shown in the error.

You can fix this by removing the `value()` method entirely, as it's not actually doing anything, or by converting to an instance method, instead of a static (`Shared`) method.

---

While I'm here, it also looks like you're trying to re-use the connection object throughout a class, form, or application. *This is a mistake.* Thanks to a feature in ADO.Net called **connection pooling**, these connection objects are intended to be *short-lived*, ideally as part of a `Using` block. You really should create a brand new connection for every query.
Really.

Comment: Nice catch - `value()` is static! Maybe one of the 123 warnings has to do with calling a static method on an instance. Or as you said there are two classes... As for the assignment, the assignment to Value shouldn't be what's calling the screenshot function. Add returns a SqlParameter which has a [Value property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.value?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)